# Merge two DataFrame columns into a new column with delimeter in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a base DataFrame with all of my calculations over a set of imported financial data.

I would like to merge two columns within this base DataFrame so that when I export to an excel worksheet, the final product is one cell (comprised of two pieces of DataFrame column data) separated the data by a delimiter, such as ' / '.

For instance:

Output of `df['Cum Days Up'] = 5`

and

Output of `df['Max Days Up'] = 10`

Ideally, I would like to merge this into one new column within my DataFrame such that the final product in both the DataFrame and excel export is:

```
df['Cum Days Up / Max'] = 5 / 10
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, also where is the raw data, your code, expected output?

Comment: convert to string with `astype` and concatenate

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function with axis=1.

Lets say you have a dataframe named df with the following columns:

```
df['Cum Days Up'] = 5
df['Max Days Up'] = 10
```

You can use the apply function with axis=1, which returns a series where each row value is the output of the given function on the corresponding row in the dataframe:

```
df['merged'] = A.apply(lambda r: '%s / %s' % (r['Cum Days Up'], r['Max Days Up']), axis=1)
```

This will give you:

```
   Cum Days Up  Max Days Up  merged
0            5           10  5 / 10
1            5           10  5 / 10
2            5           10  5 / 10
```

Now, you can use to_csv() to export to dataframe into a csv file.